# Mysterious XHTML Validation Error

Tags: validation, xhtml, http-compression, xhtml-transitional

i am trying to validate homepage of my new website and looks like i have a mysterious trouble.

If i use W3C Validator's copy-paste page source function, i only receive one warning and my page validates.

However if i use link input to validate my page it displays following error:

```
A fatal error occurred when attempting to decode response body from http://www.yoursite.com/. Either we do not support the content encoding specified ("gzip"), or an error occurred while decoding it.
```

The error was: Can't gunzip content

My site is:

[pansiyon rezervasyon portalı](http://www.pansiyonrezervasyon.com)

Would anyone help me on this issue?
Is my page valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few warnings I get, such as anchors being identified by name rather than id/class, URI's being malformed (example: /desktopmodules/dnnforge - where are they/images/uovisitors.gif), and inputs using XML id syntax.

EDITED for warnings.

```
Result: 0 errors / 22 warnings

line 23 column 1 - Warning: <input> ID "__EVENTTARGET" uses XML ID syntax
line 24 column 1 - Warning: <input> ID "__EVENTARGUMENT" uses XML ID syntax
line 412 column 2 - Warning: <img> escaping malformed URI reference
line 412 column 312 - Warning: <img> escaping malformed URI reference
line 662 column 348 - Warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
line 662 column 514 - Warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
line 662 column 698 - Warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
line 662 column 882 - Warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
line 662 column 1045 - Warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
line 662 column 1258 - Warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
line 717 column 9 - Warning: <input> ID "__dnnVariable" uses XML ID syntax
line 730 column 38 - Warning: <input> ID "__VIEWSTATE" uses XML ID syntax
line 5 column 1460 - Warning: trimming empty <style>
line 165 column 53 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 183 column 74 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 211 column 1 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 252 column 66 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 304 column 77 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 329 column 1 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 356 column 1 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 399 column 1 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
line 423 column 1 - Warning: <a> cannot copy name attribute to id
Info: Doctype given is "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
Info: Document content looks like XHTML 1.0 Transitional
```

Comment: Can you post your full list of warnings and errors (if any listed)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the validator service does not support gzip encoded content sent by your web server. This is not quite of a problem. If your page validates with copy-pasting the source code it means that it is valid.

Comment: But hang on, if the reported error is "can't gunzip", it sounds like it *knows* what gzipping is (since it knows how to undo it), it just can't gunzip *this content*, no?